# Sidebar Height Issue with Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3yHm.png)I am having issues while implementing Sidebar with mouse scrolling. If i drag the scroll manually with mouse, the sidebar leaves some white space and not able to map with the page height.

```js
$(window).on('scroll resize', function() {
  var marginTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var marginFooter = $('#divFooter').height();
  var limit = $("#divMain").height() - $("#navMenu").height();
  if (marginTop < limit) {
    $("#navMenu").css("margin-top", marginTop);
  }
});
```

```css
#navMenu {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10001;
}

#divMain {
  padding: 0 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navMenu">
  <ucl:ucNavMenu ID="ucNavMenu" runat="server" />
</div>
<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>

//div for entire page content inculding page header menu
<div id="divMain"> content </div>
```

Comment: you have to provide more information and code please.

Comment: @MattOpen: Kindly let me know what more information is required here?

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle then you will see which information is missing. Your code looks like asp.net, so better you tag it also.